# How to share an Internet connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a laptop with a Wi-Fi net connection. I also have 2 desktop computers that I would like to have access the net for Windows updates.

All 3 computers have the net connect plugs and are all running Windows 7. In the simple step-by-step way, how do I connect them all? I see many similar topic questions, but all are too technical. It would take months to look up and learn all the technobabble and even then there is no knowing if any would be useful.

Comment: VPN comes in my mind. You can see the Windows setup guide to see how to make one.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry to tell you this, but this site is not an educational "step-by-step" instructional site. This is a place to ask questions about specific issues you are having. This question is too general and will likely lead to debate and opinion based answers. You can read **[ask]** to learn more about how to use this site.

Comment: It'd greatly help if you could at least show us what questions you found and what specifically you didn't understand from them. Then we can help you solve the issues.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that the laptop has a Wi-Fi connection and I guess that you mean an USB dongle.

I am afraid that there is no easy or effective way to share the connection from the USB dongle on the laptop to your other computers. Specially not if you have a not so high level of technical experience.

I would recommend that you buy a router that has an USB port for your Wi-Fi dongle and connect your computers via cable or Wi-Fi from it.

[image]